# SQL join over multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

With a statement like this, I can get recipe names along with how many
ingredients each one of them has.

```
SELECT
r.name, COUNT(i.id) as num_ingredients
FROM recipes AS r
    LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients ON r.id = recipe_ingredients.recipe_id
    LEFT JOIN ingredients AS i ON recipe_ingredients.ingredient_id = i.id
GROUP BY r.id
```

How would I add chefs.name to my `SELECT` along with data that I already have?

[image: table schema]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
r.name, COUNT(i.id) as num_ingredients, che.name AS chefs_name
FROM recipes AS r
    LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients ON r.id = recipe_ingredients.recipe_id
    LEFT JOIN ingredients AS i ON recipe_ingredients.ingredient_id = i.id
    LEFT JOIN chefs AS che ON r.chef_id = che.id
GROUP BY r.id
```

If I understood, you would like to JOIN chefs table also and select its name.

You have to alias it in the SELECT statement because you select 2 columns with the same name.

I also think that the data type for column recipes.chef_id should be the same as chefs.id (both int(11) or int(255)).

Comment: I was confused if I could continue chaining `LEFT JOIN` on `chefs`, because of previous linking over `recipe_ingredients`.. It's actually lot easier than I thought.. ;)